# why typescript can not infer type of expression

Tags: typescript, expression, type-inference

Why one one of these snippets gives TSC error and other does not give?
Both of them create same result. nameParts is an array of strings.

```
  if(nameParts[nameParts.length-1]){

    //error: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    //   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    const lastName:string = nameParts[nameParts.length-1];

  }



  const lastWord = nameParts[nameParts.length-1];
  if(lastWord){
    const lastName:string = lastWord;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript has pragmatic limits on the depth of analysis it does. With the `const` declaration, it's trivial to see that `lastWord` won't be `undefined`, but without it TypeScript would need to remember that it's seen the guard on `nameParts[nameParts.length-1]` and that there's been no intervening code that might change `nameParts[nameParts.length-1]` (by assigning to it, using `pop`, using `shift`, etc., etc.). To avoid making the compiler too complex and/or too slow, it just doesn't go that far in the analysis — not least because if you want it to, you can use your second approach with the `const`.

Comment: There's probably a good dupetarget for this, but I don't have a good library of dupetargets for TypeScript questions yet and haven't found it yet...

Comment: "lastWord" can't be undefined as you verify it in your "if". Even if it is not ideal, you still can add "!" at the end to exclude the "undefined" type.

Comment: @bossno - You can, but assertions like that tend to introduce bugs as the code evolves (for instance, someone adds a `push` or `pop` before that line of code). I'm sure that's what you meant by not ideal, but I'd go a bit further than that. :-D